# Entity Framework class instantiation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am facing a problem where my **entity framework** keeps behaving weirdly when I try to instantiate any class. I am trying to use the default **usermanager** behaviour to store data in my database.

***Once I start instantiating a new notification before it adds that notification to the list of notifications available in the application user class it persists those changes and process an error from entity framework saying that there is a multiplicity problem***, how can I tell entity framework to not persist changes once I instantiate a class cf here is my controller code :

```
public string AddFriend(string AddedUserId)
{
    var AddedUser = UserManager.FindById(AddedUserId);
    var AddingUser = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    var friendship = new Friend(AddingUser, AddedUser) { IsInvitation = true 
    };
    AddingUser.Friends.Add(friendship);
    AddedUser.Notifications.Add(new Notification(AddingUser,
        "Friend Invitation", 
        "The user " + AddingUser.FirstName + " " + AddingUser.LastName + 
        "Sent you a friend invitation", friendship));
    UserManager.Update(AddedUser);
    UserManager.Update(AddingUser);
    return "Friend was added successfully";
}
```

my Notification class :

```
[Table("Notifications")]
public class Notification
{
    [Key]
    public int NotificationId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ApplicationUser AssociatedUser { get; set; }
    public Friend AssociatedFrienship { get; set; }
    public GroupMember AssociatedGroup { get; set; }
    public ChannelMember AssociatedChannel { get; set; }
    public Message AssociatedMessage { get; set; }
    public bool Consulted { get; set; }

    public Notification()
    {
    }

    public Notification(ApplicationUser associatedUser, string title, string content, Friend associatedFriend = null, GroupMember associatedGroup = null, ChannelMember associatedChannel = null, Message associatedMessage = null)
    {
        AssociatedUser = associatedUser;
        Title = title;
        Content = content;
        AssociatedChannel = associatedChannel;
        AssociatedGroup = associatedGroup;
        AssociatedFrienship = associatedFriend;
        AssociatedMessage = associatedMessage;
        Consulted = false;
    }
}
```

my ApplicationUser class:

```
public partial class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual List<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
}
```

my FluentAPI code :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Notification>()
            .HasRequired(c => c.AssociatedUser)
            .WithMany(c => c.Notifications);
```

The error i get is on the line : > UserManager.Update(addedUser); It says **entity framework constraints violation, the multiplicity of role (Notification_AssociatedUser_Target) of the relation (Qwirk.Models.Notification_AssociatedUser) is 1 or 0..1.**
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: What kind of relationship you want to build with `Notification` & `AssociatedUser` tables? First give a try adding `HasForeignKey` in `modelBuilder.Entity<Notification>()` based from table structure.

Comment: A notification can have only one associatedUser wish is the one who will receive the notification, and a applicationUser can have many notifications assigned to him. For the HasForeignKey on the modelBuilder i already tried adding it to the model, by just specifying another field on my Notification and linking it with Fluent API it seems that, it doesn't solve the problem at all.

Comment: Are you want to apply 1..n relationship between `ApplicationUser` & `Notifications`? Try setting `public virtual ApplicationUser AssociatedUser { get; set; }` in Notifications & `public virtual ICollection<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }` in ApplicationUser. Then, apply this model binding: `modelBuilder.Entity<Notification>().HasRequired(c => c.AssociatedUser).WithMany(c => c.Notifications).HasForeignKey(c => c.[ForeignKeyFieldName]).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);`

Comment: I did what you told me i still have exactly the same error. This doesn't fix the problem i guess. But thanks doe! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution time, after 2 days searching the error, i finally found it:
In my controller i had to do :

```
AddedUser.Notifications.Add(new Notification(AddedUser,
    "Friend Invitation", 
    "The user " + AddingUser.FirstName + " " + AddingUser.LastName + 
    "Sent you a friend invitation", friendship));
```

AddedUser instead of addingUser yaayyyyyy i feel honestly stupid at this point lmao.